# Getting incorrect results from a python list

Tags: python-2.7

I am reading data from a postgres table and one of the fields I am reading has the following data:

```html
'1', '1', '203316-01', 'Outdoor Bistro Infrared Heated Table'
```

iterating through the dictionary, I assign these values to an attribute sg_item_list then use this field to create a list.

```
['1', '1', '203316-01', 'Outdoor Bistro Infrared Heated Table']
```

using the following python script:

```html
cnt = 0
    new_dsL = []
    for sg_item in dsL:
        sg_itemL = eval(sg_item.sg_item_list)
        print 'list printed', sg_itemL
        for i_row in sg_itemL:
            cnt += 1
            print 'printing list', cnt, i_row
            #print 'debugg i_row:',i_row[2]
            if len(i_row) >= 3 :  #and i_row[2] in boD:
                print 'debugg:',i_row[2]
                sg_item.sg_bo_ind = 'True'
        new_dsL.append(sg_item)
    dsL = new_dsL
```

I iterate through the list but I am getting incorrect results like:

```html
xxxx@xxxx /cygdrive/c/Reports/SI_Reconciliation_Reporting
 $ /cygdrive/c/Python27-64/python.exe ./bin/si_under_dev_rpt-drop-ship-orders-last-60-days.py
 list printed ['1', '1', '203316-01', 'Outdoor Bistro Infrared Heated Table']
 printing list 1 1
 printing list 2 1
 printing list 3 203316-01
 debugg: 3
 printing list 4 Outdoor Bistro Infrared Heated Table
 debugg: t
 RPT: Create the DS Last 60 Days Report. version: R1
```

I should have seen 203316-01 instead of 3 or t.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're indexing in your debug line, and getting "20**3**316-01" and "Ou**t**door Bistro Infrared Heated Table".

Comment: Thanks for that but I when condition to to if len(i_row) > 3 and i_row in boD: When I print the debugg line, it works fine  but making the modification causes more errors, this is what I am getting File "./bin/si_under_dev_rpt-drop-ship-orders-last-60-days.py", line 389, in run_report
    if len(i_row) > 3 and i_row in boD:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: doing a print It stops on line 65 with printing list 64 Laptop and Tablet Tray
printing list 65 ['1', '0', '200288-02', 'Money Grip Clip-Personalized-Silver'] How do  I solve this?

Comment: How do I make it better?

Comment: @ignacio-vazquez-abramsI opened up a new question with a link to this.